# Batch object variable use in net use command not working (System Error 67)

Tags: batch-file, cmd

What I'm trying to make is a simple script to choose a network drive to be mounted then unmounted from a list. The information is storred in a CSV file.
The script first reads the CSV file and stores the parameters in an array of objects.
When I try to use the parameters in a net use command, I get a `System Error 67`.
Here is my code :

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set i=0
for /f "usebackq skip=1 tokens=1-4 delims=;" %%a in ("data.csv") do (
    set list[!i!].name=%%a
    set list[!i!].endpoint=%%b
    set list[!i!].user=%%c
    set list[!i!].pwd=%%d
    set /a i=!i!+1
)

set "x = 0" 
:SymLoop 
if defined list[%x%] ( 
   call echo %list[%x%]%% 
   set /a "x+=1"
   goto :SymLoop 
)
set /a "x+=1"

for /l %%i in (0 1 %x%) do  (
   call echo %%i %%list[%%i].name%%
)
set /p tomount=Which network drive would you like to mount ? 

net use z: %%list[%tomount%].endpoint%% /user:%%list[%tomount%].user%% %%list[%tomount%].pwd%%

set /p dummy=Hit ENTER to unmount and exit...
net use z: /delete

pause
```

The CSV file looks like this (these are examples, I use correct data in my scenario):

```
Nom;Endpoint;ID;Password
test1;\\1.1.1.1\dir1\dir2;admin;pssword
test2;\\2.2.2.2\dir1\dir444;admin;testpwd
```

When I `call echo %%list[%tomount%].endpoint%% /user:%%list[%tomount%].user%% %%list[%tomount%].pwd%%`, I get the correct variables, and when I manually enter the net use command with the exact same parameters, it works too.

Do you have any idea how to solve this ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I simply forgot to use `call` before my `net use` command !
Works now.

Comment: Well, this solved the problem, but your code is confusing, you use `delayedexpansion`, then stop using it while it is still enabled. You're making lfie harder for yourself.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not used to coding in batch. I haven't tried/had the time to understand many principles, like ```DelayedExpansion```. If you have suggestions to smooth my code, I'm taking any advice!